# Discrete value supplied to continuous scale - Dataset does not have any factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I know this has already been asked, by I do not understand why I keep getting the `Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` error when trying customize my axis on this graph.

On the questions I have read it said that happened because some of the variables on the dataset were defined as factors, whic does not happen in this case.

```
df <- data.frame(Grupo = c('Tratado', 'Controle', 'Tratado', 'Controle', 'Tratado','Controle'),
                 UF = c('SP','MG','MG','SP','BA','BA'),
                 prop = c(0.166, 0.161, 0.121, 0.112, 0.092,0.084))


ggplot(df,aes(x = reorder(UF,prop), y = prop)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Grupo), position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity') +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x = 'Importância na amostra', y = 'UF') +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to think of `coord_flip` as a visual transformation that gets applied right at the end of the whole plot building process. So `prop` is your `y` variable, you apply `scale_y_continuous` to it, and then only right at the end does `coord_flip` get applied and `prop` moves to the x-axis. The fix is just to use `scale_y` instead of `scale_x`:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = reorder(UF,prop), y = prop)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = Grupo), position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity') +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_classic() +
    labs(x = 'Importância na amostra', y = 'UF') +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```